# tailwind working with variables and toggled classes

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I easily wrote this [example](https://codepen.io/den4ik_rus/pen/xxWowyz) in pure css and html

But I ran into difficulties understanding how to effectively do the same example on tailwind. I assume that without writing additional classes to switch the "active" states, this cannot be done. And you will have to put these classes in separate files. Somehow it's all difficult, because if you do this, then some of the styles will be in html, and some in other style files and you will have to compare and try to find errors. It seemed to me a very complicated process. Finding errors only in style files is a little easier if they are properly organized. IMHO

My attempt [github](https://github.com/denisso/tailwind-expo/tree/variables)

I assume that with the help of some additional tools, everything will become easier and more convenient, maybe if you write it on React and use javascript to solve some tasks. But on a clean tailwind I had problems.

My code html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <style>
            .box {
                --width: 80vw;
                --gap: 20px;
                --collapsed: calc(var(--width) / 6 - var(--gap) * 2);
                --active: calc(var(--width) - var(--width) / 3 - var(--gap));
            }
            .item.active {
                flex-basis: var(--active);
            }
            .img {
                width: var(--active);
                object-fit: cover;
                object-position: center;
                transition: transform 1s;
            }

            .item.active .img {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
        </style>
        <title>TailwindCSS Boilerplate</title>
    </head>
    <body class="">
        <div
            class="box flex mx-auto w-[var(--width)] gap-[var(--gap)] h-[calc(var(--width) / 3)]"
        >
            <div
                class="item active basis-[var(--collapsed)] overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis_1s] rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
            >
                <img
                    src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/300 "
                    alt=""
                    class="img block h-[100%]"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="item basis-[var(--collapsed)] overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis_1s] rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
            >
                <img
                    src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/600/300 "
                    alt=""
                    class="img block h-[100%]"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="item basis-[var(--collapsed)] overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis_1s] rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
            >
                <img
                    src="https://picsum.photos/id/3/600/300 "
                    alt=""
                    class="img block h-[100%]"
                />
            </div>
            <div
                class="item basis-[var(--collapsed)] overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis_1s] rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
            >
                <img
                    src="https://picsum.photos/id/4/600/300 "
                    alt=""
                    class="img block h-[100%]"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
import '../css/style.css'

const $box = document.querySelector(".box")
$box.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const $item = e.target.closest(".item")
    if (!$item) return

    for (let i = 0; i < $box.children.length; i++) {
        if ($box.children[i] === $item) {
            $box.children[i].classList.add("active")
        } else {
            $box.children[i].classList.remove("active")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The power of Tailwind in its [configuration](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration). Let's start with creating custom `w-4/5-screen` class

```js
module.exports = {
    content: [
        /** content */
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            width: {
                '4/5-screen': '80vw',
            },
        }
    },
}
```

Class can be named as you wish. But you may pass CSS variables also

```js
extend: {
    width: {
        '4/5-screen': 'var(--width)', // of course this variable should be defined somewhere
    },
}
```

Next you have `--active` variable which has calculations in it. No problem! Just pass it as STRING in config

```js
extend: {
    width: {
        '4/5-screen': 'var(--width)',
        active: 'calc(var(--width) - var(--width) / 3 - var(--gap))' // calculations
    },
}
```

If you wish, you may use [theme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) directive in these calculations - it may access any value from configuration.

```js
extend: {
    width: {
        '4/5-screen': 'var(--width)',
        active: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen") - theme("width.4/5-screen") / 3 - theme("gap.5"))' // huge calculations with theme within
    },
}
```

Note you have `flex-basis: var(--active)` property. It has same value as `w-active` class actually. Do not repeat yourself, you may set config values as function, which will return object and use `theme()` helper or any other JS functions you need. It should return string value though

```js
extend: {
    width: {
        '4/5-screen': 'var(--width)',
        active: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen") - theme("width.4/5-screen") / 3 - theme("gap.5"))' // huge calculations with theme within
    },
    flexBasis: theme => ({ // it can be a function!
        active: theme('width.active'), // pass JS theme Tailwind helper
        collapsed: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen") / 6 - theme("gap.5") * 2)', // theme('gap.5') is same as 20px, no need in new variable
    }),
    height: {
        box: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen")/3)',
    }
}
```

With these new classes your HTML would look like (I'll show only one element, the rest the same but `active` class)

*One mistake you made is `transition-[flex-basis_1s]` should be `transition-[flex-basis] duration-1000`*

```html
<style>
.box {
    --width: 80vw;
}
.item.active {
    flex-basis: var(--active); // deal with it later
}
.item.active .img {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
</style>

<div class="flex gap-5 mx-auto box w-4/5-screen h-box">
    <div
        class="item active basis-collapsed overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis] duration-1000 rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
    >
        <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/300"
            class="object-cover object-center h-full w-active"
        />
    </div>

    <!-- The rest -->
</div>
```

Now it's time for toggling classes. Despite Tailwind is not JS framework at all, you can still use CSS logic to write your own variants to "simulate" class toggling. Let's write [plugin](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#creating-a-plugin) for this

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin'); // require plugin helper

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    /** other settings */
    plugins: [
        plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
            addVariant('current', '&.active');
            addVariant('group-current', '.active &');
        })
    ],
}
```

By these two lines we've created two new variants - `current:`, which will be applied into element with `.active` class and `group-current` - applied for every child of element with `.active` class. Names of the variants could be any but unique

> NOTE - I'm not using `active` keyword, as it is already in [use](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#hover-focus-and-active). Also - `group-current` is NOT acting like any [group](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state) properties but just to keep it consistent

Add new variants into HTML

```html
<style>
.box {
    --width: 80vw;
}
</style>

<div class="flex gap-5 mx-auto box w-4/5-screen h-box">
    <div
        class="item current:basis-active active basis-collapsed overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis] duration-1000 rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
    >
        <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/300"
            class="object-cover object-center h-full group-current:translate-x-0 w-active"
        />
    </div>
    <!-- The rest -->
</div>
```

The final result is (JS has not been changed)

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: [
        /** content */
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            width: {
                '4/5-screen': 'var(--width)', // can be replaced with `80vw` - we're not using `var(--width)` anywhere
                active: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen") - theme("width.4/5-screen") / 3 - theme("gap.5"))'
            },
            flexBasis: theme => ({
                active: theme('width.active'),
                collapsed: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen") / 6 - theme("gap.5") * 2)',
            }),
            height: {
                box: 'calc(theme("width.4/5-screen")/3)',
            },
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        plugin(function({ addVariant }) {
            addVariant('current', '&.active');
            addVariant('group-current', '.active &');
        })
    ],
}
```

```html
<style>
.box {
    --width: 80vw; // kept it as an example, but it can be removed
}
</style>

<!-- Both `.box` and `.item` classes are still required for JS -->
<div class="flex gap-5 mx-auto box w-4/5-screen h-box">
    <div
        class="item current:basis-active active basis-collapsed overflow-hidden transition-[flex-basis] duration-1000 rounded-[2rem] flex-grow-[1] cursor-pointer"
    >
        <img
            src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/300"
            class="object-cover object-center h-full group-current:translate-x-0 w-active"
        />
    </div>
    <!-- The rest -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i must think about, but my imho not changed edit multiple files for make simple things it not very good. Maybe I'll change my point of view later. Most of all, I am interested in how well you can perceive and maintain a huge number of classes in one line, which are partly classes from tailwind, partly your own classes and tailwind.config, partly these are some of our @layer components and utillites from a css file and if we use some tailwind ui framework, a few more classes are added to them.

Comment: First Perception and understanding: I use VS Code with the tailwind plugin, which helps a little, but does not solve my main problem of how to effectively perceive visually a long string of classes whose names may not be familiar to me, because they have custom names.

The second is Maintenance and changes: Everything is also divided into classes in the dev tools browser and it is quite difficult to immediately understand where in the code something needs to be changed, it can be either a css file or a config file or you need to add something to html.

Comment: I don't know, in my opinion Tailwind has mostly good self-explained utility class names and you will understand on the fly where this class is same from - native, custom or config. It you need to reuse multiple utilities or shorten - use `@apply` [directive](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply). I personally almost never have any issue with code maintenance on Tailwind (the only missing thing I would like to have is grouping states)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka in your example you define `--width` as an inline style, is it possible to define it in the `class` for the `div` to avoid CSP that doesn't allow inline styles?

Comment: @ecoe you [can](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yLOjKagEaj) if I understood your question. Tailwind allows you to write inline styles as classes (I personally see no big difference and never use it). I used CSS variable in this example as question has it